# How to solve a linear program with additional equality constraints?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

The following optimization problem
$$\max_{\substack{x \ge 0,\\Ax^T+b^T\ge 0}} c x^T$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a linear program in $n$ variables with $m$ constraints (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) and is well studied (in particular there exist a batch of standard methods to deal with such an optimization).

I, however, am trying to solve a slightly different optimization:
$$\max_{\substack{x \ge 0,\\Ax^T+b^T\ge 0,\\d x^T = \alpha}} c x^T$$
where $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha>0$ is a scalar.  Namely, an equality constraint is added to the linear program.  I was wondering if there also exist standard methods to approach the latter?

Comment: There many methods, some more efficient, some more straight forward. Hint: $s=t$ iff $s\le t$ and $s\ge t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference, you solve it using exactly the same methods. The form described in your link is just one standard form. Linear programming means optimization of a linear objective under linear equalities and linear inequalities.

Comment: You're right!  Indeed I realize that I've asked a very silly question!  All nice standard machinery works in this case as well.